# How to get data from an object with arrays/strings and then pass that data to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass information from one component to another via props in ReactJS. I'm trying to access the inside of an array that has a string of information (picture included), and then I'm trying to get that information accessible to my return() function in the component so I can use it in a modal.

This is the component that I passed the props into:

```
class OfferActionPreviewModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      success: false,
      action: [],
      offerActions: []
    };
    this.toggleSuccess = this.toggleSuccess.bind(this);
  }

  toggleSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      success: !this.state.success
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderAdvertiserForm();
  }

  renderAdvertiserForm = () => {
    const {
      offerAction,
      offerActionTriggers,
      triggers,
      offer
    } = this.props;
    console.log(offerActionTriggers);
    return (
      <form>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleSuccess}>
          {offerAction.name} - <em>{offerAction.id}</em>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <div>
            <Row>
              <Col lg={6}>
                <Label>Post Name</Label>
                <Field
                  name='offerActions.name'
                  type='text'
                  component={renderField}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col lg={6}>
                <Label>Post Method</Label>

                  {offerAction.postMethod}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <br />
            <Row>
              <Col lg={12}>
                <Label>URL</Label>

                  {offerAction.url}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <br />

          </div>
          <br />
        </ModalBody>
      </form>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='animated'>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.success}
          toggle={this.toggleSuccess}
          className='modal-info'
        >
          {this.renderAdvertiserForm()}
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(OfferActionPreviewModal);
```

I'm trying to access **inside** the **OfferActionTriggers**, to the **OfferActionCriteria** part of the object, and I've included an image of the object for reference.

Thanks for all help in advance. [image]

Comment: Are you trying to display each `offereAction` inside the model (in the image you have array of 3 objects having `offereAction`) or just one `offereAction` ?

Comment: I am trying to display each offerAction in a separate modal, depending on the offer's ID @TRomesh

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nested Object Destructuring for this purpose like this
`const {offerAction:{OfferActionCriteria,offerActionPost:{url,name,id,postMethod}}} =
this.props;` to access the **OfferActionCriteria** object. inside **renderAdvertiserForm** function.

```
renderAdvertiserForm = () => {
const {offerAction:{OfferActionCriteria,offerActionPost:{url,name,id,postMethod}}} = this.props;
        console.log(OfferActionCriteria);
        return (
          <form>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleSuccess}>
              {name} - <em>{id}</em>
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <div>
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={6}>
                    <Label>Post Name</Label>
                    <Field
                      name='name'
                      type='text'
                      component={renderField}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col lg={6}>
                    <Label>Post Method</Label>

                      {postMethod}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <br />
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={12}>
                    <Label>URL</Label>

                      {offerAction.url}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <br />

              </div>
              <br />
            </ModalBody>
          </form>
        );
      };
```

Comment: that's giving me an undefined response

Comment: can you share your code via codesandbox?. My answers is based on the fact that you have passed an object- `OfferAction` (given in the diagram) OfferActionPreviewModal

Comment: I have passed an object called `OfferActionTriggers` and inside that object is `OfferAction`